# Plotting the Bell state on a Bloch sphere

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state, bloch-sphere, bell-basis

How can you plot the bell state on a Bloch sphere?

```
bell = QuantumCircuit(2)

bell.h(0)

bell.x(1)

bell.cx(0,1)
```

Is there any good reference for understanding how to create a bell state using a quantum circuit?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot plot the Bell state using a **single** Bloch sphere, as it can be used exclusively for a single qubit representation.

However, there exist other ways to visualize the Bell state.

One would be using multivector Bloch representations for each qubit separately: `plot_bloch_multivector()` from [Qiskit](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/quantum-hardware/density-matrix).

[image: Bell state]

As you can see, the spheres are empty. This is because the two qubits are **maximally entangled**.

Another representation is called [qsphere](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.visualization.plot_state_qsphere.html). The size of the points is proportional to the probability of measuring the corresponding configuration. The phase is represented by color.

[image: qsphere]